# NoClassDefFoundError when connecting Toplink Workbench to the database

Tags: toplink

I am using TopLink Mapping Worknbench version 9.0.3.5.  When I try to connect to the database I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/dms/instrument/ExecutionContextForJDBC
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:322)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:151)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:608)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
    at oracle.toplink.workbench.model.db.BldrDatabase.login(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.toplink.workbench.ui.BldrMainView.login(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.toplink.workbench.ui.BldrActionManager$32.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:302)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1050)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1091)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:231)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5517)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3129)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added .\lib\dms.jar; to the classpath in the workbench.cmd to solve this issue.